# How to secure a slim 3 application with user authentifcation

Tags: php, security, authentication, slim-3

I'm quiet new to slim, but I want to give it a try. I have created an application, which uses twig as view rendering.

A user should authenticate against a database (via a login form), before access administration. I created a login form, but now I'm stuck.

I found some libraries and middleware, helping with basic HTTP Authentification, but that is not quiet what I want. 
I simply could store a session var, after checking the users information with my database, but is this actually secure? 
Some people using authentication libraries, like Zend/Authentification oder Session. 
Also, there is the whole token based authentification, but I don't know, if I should use this, when not creating an REST application.

I just want to understand, what does mean "secure" in a slim3 application and how to handle a user login with all it's aspects, to create a secure backend experience. Are there any libraries I should use, to build a middleware around?

Thanks for clarification/help.

Answer (score 0):

I've been building applications in Slim for a little over 1 years, and I went through the same problem at the beginning, my tip for you is, as slim is meant to be a simple framework, it has nothing as default, so you you need to build the security of your application;

I started by trying some authentication libs, but starting to build mine.

Basically what i used

First I used Basiauth, with CSRF

Then I set out to build OAuth 2 authentication, ensuring token access to resources, and access rules.

For this I used a very powerful library https://oauth2.thephpleague.com/

Comment: I started implementing zend_auth library, along with some adapters. It's working quiet nice. The whole concept of slim is quiet confusion the first time, because as you said, it's mostly an empty framework.

I want to look at token access/authentication, when building small apis, so I will keep this in mind.

Thanks for your answer. :)